# How to remove double quotes in json encoded array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, double, quote

There are similar questions I have not understood explanation (my question is simpler..) 
inside php :

`echo json_encode(array("value" => $data));`

returns me a JSON line like:

`{"value":"100"}`     (assuming 100 is $data)

How can I get a json like :

`{"value":100}`     ($data NOT doublequoted) ??

Thank you

Comment: You're probably after the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` encode option.

Comment: Technically, all JSON in PHP should be wrapped in "" (double quotes), even the PHP-variables. PHP doesn't differentiate between "100" and 100, so I don't really understand the need.

Comment: JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK works IF the element of the array is a number, if like my case it is a variable, array("value" => $data) it doesn't work , still return the numeric value of $data doublequoted, any workaround ?

Comment: YOU ARE CORRECT !   JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK works also if the element is a variable !!  My mistake the $data variable content was not pure numeric THANKS

Answer (score 4):

You should probably use [`JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) as the 2nd argument to [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) method of PHP like this:

```
$arr = ['value' => '100'];
$json_encoded = json_encode($arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
// echo $json_encoded --- "{"value":100}"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is not worknig for comma seperated values